# Output string length and classical Fibonacci sequence in a web page

Tags: javascript, strings, html5, fibonacci-sequence

I wrote a JavaScript and XHTML webpage. I think the format of the output is not better or the validation process is not as it is supposed to be. How can I improve the code? How can I make it more efficient?

There are two text boxes. First, it takes a sentence and returns the length. Second, it takes an integer and returns that number of classical Fibonacci numbers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<titile></title>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getStrLen(){
        var msgDiv = document.getElementById('textbox1');
    document.getElementById('msg').textContent = msgDiv.value.split('').length;

}
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 1;
var ONE = 1;
function genFibonacci(times){
    if(times <=0){return;}
     a = b;
    b = c;
    c = a + b;





        document.getElementById('fibseq').textContent += a.toString() + (times > ONE ? ", " : " ");

        genFibonacci(times - 1, false); 
}

function outFib(){

genFibonacci(document.getElementById('fibText').value);
}

</script>

<button id="lenClick" onclick="getStrLen()">String Length</button>
Enter a sentence or multiple ones: <input type="text" id="textbox1"></input>
<br/>

Number of characters in this sentence is: <span id="msg">
</span>
<br/>

<input type="text" id="fibText"></input>
<button id="fibClick" onclick="outFib()">Generate Fibonacci Sequence</button><div id="fibseq"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Getting the length of a string

You split the string into characters and then you count the array's length. While this works, there's an even simpler way of doing it, using the [`length` property of a `String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length):

```
const length = msgDiv.value.length;
```

## Changing `getStrLen`

You can cache the DOM elements. Then you don't need to re-query them, each time the function is called:

```
const strlenInput = document.getElementById('textbox1');
const strlenDisplay = document.getElementById('msg');

const getStrLen = () => {
    strlenDisplay.textContent = strlenInput.value.length;
}
```

Now this alone won't work in the `head`-element of your document, as both elements are not available yet. You can either:

- wait until the DOM is ready to run that script, like `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) { […] }`, or
- place the Javascript at the end of your page instead

This is explained in detail here: [$(document).ready(function(){}); vs script at the bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6026645/1456376).

## Creating the Fibonacci sequence

`genFibonacci()` takes one parameter, so you pass an unused parameter, when calling the function recursively:

```
genFibonacci(times - 1, false);
```

---

There's a flaw in your logic: You don't reset the values each time the button is clicked. If the user's input is `1` and they hit the generate button 5 times, the result is not `0` but:

```
 0 1 1 2 3
```

---

With this in mind, let's try to change your algorithm, that it won't rely on external variables. We also don't necessarily need recursion here:

```
const getFibonacciValues = (n) => {
    const values = [];

    if (n >= 1) {
        values.push(0);
    }

    if (n >= 2) {
        values.push(1);
    }

    for (let i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
        values.push(values[i - 2] + values[i -1]);
    }

    return values;
}
```

Now we have a function, which purpose is solely to create the values. It doesn't have a clue, how you're going to output them. `outFib()` is doing this for us now:

```
const outFib = () => {
    const n = fibInput.value;
    const values = getFibonacciValues(n);
    fibDisplay.textContent = values.join(', ');
}
```

Now, this still has flaws, so we add a little bit of validation at least:

- use `parseInt` to parse the value
- check whether the input is at least `1`
- check whether the input is a number

The final result could look like this:

```js
const fibButton = document.getElementById('fibClick');
const fibInput = document.getElementById('fibText');
const fibDisplay = document.getElementById('fibseq');

const getFibonacciValues = (n) => {
    const values = [];

    if (n >= 1) {
        values.push(0);
    }
    
    if (n >= 2) {
        values.push(1);
    }
    
    for (let i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
        values.push(values[i - 2] + values[i -1]);
    }

    return values;
};

const outFib = () => {
    const n = parseInt(fibInput.value);

    if (n < 1 || isNaN(n)) {
        fibDisplay.textContent = 'Please insert a number greater than 0';
        return;
    }
    
    const values = getFibonacciValues(n);
    fibDisplay.textContent = values.join(', ');
};

fibClick.addEventListener('click', outFib);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fibText">
<button id="fibClick">Generate Fibonacci Sequence</button>
<div id="fibseq"></div>
```

## Further improvements

This will fail for large inputs – try `2000` for example. You'll get a lot of `Infinity`.

You can take a look into [bigNumber.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/) or you can set an upper limit, like `if (n > 1000) { fibDisplay.textContent = 'Too large'; return; }` or you could store all values for your maximum `n`.

---

Calculating all numbers over and over again is some overhead you could avoid. You could cache already calculated values, and only add new values if `n > values.length`. Alternatively you can store all numbers beforehand, which is an increase in memory usage, but your runtime becomes incredibly fast, as all you have left is:

```
const values = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, …];
const output = values.splice(0, n);
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>My [first answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/203085/21444) is looking at the JavaScript and as it became fairly long, I'll add another one containing some notices regarding style and markup.</sup>

---

## Formatting

Try to indent your code properly:

> ```
> function getStrLen(){
>         var msgDiv = document.getElementById('textbox1');
>     document.getElementById('msg').textContent = msgDiv.value.split('').length;
> }
>
> function outFib(){
>
> genFibonacci(document.getElementById('fibText').value);
> }
> ```

---

Even if you can shorten things like here:

```
if(times <=0){return;}
```

I would format it like this to increase readability:

```
if (times <= 0) {
    return;
}
```

## Variable declaration

Try to use `const`, `let` and `var` keywords when appropriate. You can read more about the differences especially between `var` und `let` here: [What's the difference between using “let” and “var” to declare a variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav)
.

---

Try to use descriptive variable names. It will be hard to guess in a week what these are:

> ```
> var a = 0;
> var b = 0;
> var c = 1;
> ```

## HTML

`input` does not have a closing tag:

> ```
> <input type="text" id="textbox1"></input>
> ```

This is simply:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1">
```

---

Form elements should actually be wrapped in a `form`-element or be attached to a form using the `form`-attribute. While this isn't an issue in all browsers, technically it's invalid HTML.